# Python 2 & 3 compatibility with `super` and classes who were old-style in Py2 but became new-style in Py3

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, super

I have [a project](https://github.com/exhuma/config_resolver) which uses `SafeConfigParser` and I want it to be Python2 and 3 compatible. Now, `SafeConfigParser` is deprecated since Python 3.2 and I find the deprecation warning annoying. So I went about my business to remedy that.

First (and much older, already solved problem): `SafeConfigParser` is an old-style class in Python2 so I cannot call `super` in my descendant class. To have a more consistent behaviour, I wrote the following:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    class ConfigResolverBase(object, SafeConfigParser):
        """
        A default "base" object simplifying Python 2 and Python 3
        compatibility.
        """
        pass
except TypeError:
    # Python 3
    class ConfigResolverBase(SafeConfigParser):
        """
        A default "base" object simplifying Python 2 and Python 3
        compatibility.
        """
        pass
```

This worked fine to make the class new-style if necessary. To get rid of the `DeprecationWarning` I changed the code into this:

```
if sys.hexversion < 0x030000F0:
    # Python 2
    class ConfigResolverBase(object, SafeConfigParser):
        """
        A default "base" object simplifying Python 2 and Python 3
        compatibility.
        """
        pass
else:
    # Python 3
    class ConfigResolverBase(ConfigParser):
        """
        A default "base" object simplifying Python 2 and Python 3
        compatibility.
        """
        pass
```

Along the way I also fixed a line I missed to change earlier:

```
@@ -275,7 +276,7 @@ class Config(ConfigResolverBase):
             have_default = False

         try:
-            value = SafeConfigParser.get(self, section, option, **kwargs)
+            value = super(Config, self).get(section, option, **kwargs)
             return value
         except (NoSectionError, NoOptionError) as exc:
             if have_default:
```

And *that* change caused an interesting error:

```
AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute '_sections'
```

Which let me to believe that `__init__` of `ConfigParser` was not called. And indeed making the following change fixed that:

```
- class ConfigResolverBase(object, SafeConfigParser):
+ class ConfigResolverBase(SafeConfigParser, object):
```

My code is now working fine for both Python 2 and 3, but whant I am unsure about is: Is the proxy returned by `super` always the same?" In my case I inherit from both `object` and `SafeConfigParser`. Swapping the two bases in my class definition made `super` return the right one. But is this guaranteed to be stable across all Python implementations on all platforms? Or should I explicitly call `SafeConfigParser.get(self, ...)`? Which is after-all the "old way" of calling the base...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is guaranteed stable across Python versions. The search order is called the Method Resolution Order, or MRO, and this order has been the same since Python 2.3.

For more details on how the order is determined, see the [Python 2.3 Method Resolution Order documentation](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

You can inspect the MRO by looking at the `.__mro__` attribute of a given class; it is a tuple of the classes in method-resolution order.

Comment: Thanks for the lightning fast answer! I was looking about the MRO, but I was not entirely sure it was stable. Thanks for confirming this.

Answer (score 0):

I was also doing some work using `SafeConfigParser`. To make it work with old-style and new-style classes, both, you can check if it is a subclass of `object` or not. New-style classes inherit from `object`, whereas old-style classes don't.

Example:

```
class MyClass(SafeConfigParser):
    def __init__(self):
        if issubclass(SafeConfigParser, object):
            # new style class, call super
            super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        else:
            # old style class, call __init__ manually
            SafeConfigParser.__init__(self)
```